# Solving the system $2x^2 = \frac{y}{z}+\frac{z}{y}$, $2y^2 = \frac{z}{x}+\frac{x}{z}$, $2z^2 = \frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

> Find all triplets $\{ x, y, z\}$, such that all three of them are real and nonzero, and satisfies:
> $$2x^2 = \frac{y}{z}+\frac{z}{y}$$
> $$2y^2 = \frac{z}{x}+\frac{x}{z}$$
> $$2z^2 = \frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}$$

I'm stuck in this problem. My first thought was that the only solutions that are possible are $\{ 1, 1, 1 \}$ and $\{ -1, -1, -1\}$, but I do not know how to prove that these are the only solutions. I know for a fact that there seems something "fishy" about the fractions, and I am thinking of changing those into:

$$2x^2yz=y^2+z^2$$

$$2y^2xz=x^2+z^2$$

$$2z^2xy=y^2+x^2$$
but I do not know how to proceed from here. Can anybody give me a hint on how to proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

all of x,y,z have the same sign.
assume x,y,z>0.
assume $x\geq y\geq z$
$$\frac{y}{z}+\frac{z}{y}=2x^2\geq 2y^2=\frac{z}{x}+\frac{x}{z}$$
$$\frac{y}{z}\geq \frac{x}{z}$$
$$y\geq x$$
$$x=y$$
$$2z^2=\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}=2$$
$$z=1$$
$$2x^2=x+1/x$$
$$2x^3=x^2+1$$
$$2x^3-x^2-1=0$$
$$(x-1)(2x^2+x+1)=0$$
$$x=1$$
$$x=y=z=1$$
dropping the assumption that all are positive, (x,y,z)=(1,1,1) or (-1,-1,-1).
there might be a more elegant solution.

Comment: How do you know that all of x, y, z have the same signs?

Comment: @MarioPrix suppose 2 of them have different signs. WLOG x,y. then $2z^2=x/y+y/x<0$.

Comment: OIC, thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 2):

> $$2x^2yz=y^2+z^2 \\ 2y^2xz=x^2+z^2$$

Subtracting the two:

$$
\require{cancel}
2xyz(x-y) = y^2 + \bcancel{z^2} - x^2 - \bcancel{z^2} = (y-x)(y+x)
$$

If $\,y \ne x\,$, after canceling out the $\,(x-y)\,$ factor $\,2xyz=-x-y\,$, then it follows by symmetry that $\,2xyz =-y-z=-z-x\,$, so $\,x = y\,$ i.e. contradiction.

This leaves the case $\,x=y\,$, so $\,x=y=z\,$ by symmetry, and the equations reduce to $\,2x^2=2\,$.

Comment: This is the way to go!  +1